# How can I remove all ocurance of , and I from a string using REGEXP_REPLACE in mysql-10.4.24-MariaDB?

Tags: mariadb

How can I remove all occurrence of , and I from a string using REGEXP_REPLACE?
Tried the following but it doesn't work

```
regexp_replace('123,|4abcd, aaa|,qqq|a', '|,', '', 'g')
```

Sorry I meant , and |.

Comment: Why use regex? Why not just `replace(replace('123,|4abcd, aaa|,qqq|a', '*', ''), '|', '')`?

Comment: because regexp_replace accepts list of characters rather that writing separate  replace for each charcater.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's convenient that `|` and `*` lose their special meaning inside a character class (the square brackets):

```
mysql> select regexp_replace('123*,|4abcd, aaa|,qqq|a', '[|*,]', '') as s;
+------------------+
| s                |
+------------------+
| 1234abcd aaaqqqa |
+------------------+
```

Notice the use of square brackets for the regular expression. This means to match any one of the characters in the brackets.

Also the final argument you used, `'g'`, is not supported, and not necessary. I suppose you think it means to apply the replacement multiple times, like in vim when you do `s/regexp/string/g`. But in the case of MySQL and MariaDB, `REGEXP_REPLACE()` applies the replace on all matches in the string by default.

Demonstration using MariaDB 10.4: https://dbfiddle.uk/ZFNMTfJ6

Comment: If you don't get the same result, please show the result of `SELECT VERSION();`

Comment: Sorry I meant , and |.

Comment: I have updated the example in my answer to show removal of '`,`' works the same as the other characters.

Comment: This is not working for me. I am using SaaS system and I don't know where to find version.

Comment: Can you run an SQL query?

Comment: No, Our SaaS system provides a Report builder and we can include function like regexp_replace, Max, Sum etc. I don't get any errors though when including your statement in the Report builder but I do not get the desired result.

Comment: What happens if you try to run a report with `VERSION()` as the function?

Comment: The report breaks with the error message: The report contains invalid formula or criteria. Refer to the Report Builder Help panel for a list of accepted functions.

Comment: That sounds like you're not even using MySQL as the back-end RDBMS. How sure are you about that?

Comment: Just confirmed we are using mysql-4.0.17

Comment: MySQL 4.0.17 was released 2003-12-14. The `REGEXP_REPLACE()` function is supported only in MySQL 8.0. By running such an old version of the MySQL software, you're also losing out on many other features, bug fixes, and performance improvements developed over the past two decades.

Comment: Documentation for MySQL 3.23-4.0-4.1 can be found at https://downloads.mysql.com/docs/refman-4.1-en.a4.pdf

Comment: Confirmed the `VERSION()` function was added in MySQL 4.1.25 in 2008. In older versions, you could check the version with `SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE 'version';`

Comment: Sorry I have been rectified, we are using 10.4.24-MariaDB. Sorry for the misinformation.